# Laravel update request validation how to get the id

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I have managed to set correctly my update request for my users but when I do exactly the same for another table (clusters), I cannot get the id in the clusterrequest validation.

Here is what I have for my clusters:
routes:

```
Route::post('clusterFormUpdate/{id}', ['uses'=>'ClusterController@postFormUpdate','middleware' => ['permission:user-edit']]);
```

Controller:

```
public function postFormUpdate(ClusterUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();
```

ClusterUpdateRequest:

```
...
public function rules()
{

    $id = $this->id;
    dd($id);

    return [
        'name'      => 'required|max:255|unique:clusters,name,' . $id . ',id',
        'countries' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

When I run this, I get null.

If I try the same for my user table, I get the id that is printed correctly so I was wondering where I can look for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: That is really strange, now it works with changing it to id in the route... The strange thing is that I am using exactly the same model for all my routes and controllers and for the other ones, it is working fine...

Comment: The reason it now works is because of the magic `__get()` method in the base Request class. If it can't find the value in the request it will assume you're trying to get the value from the route. This will **not** work if you have `id` in the `QueryString` or the `POST` request so it is potentially better to be explicit (use the `param()` method).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the id in the `Request` you can use the `route()` method:

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->route('n'); //or whatever it is named in the route
    
    return [ 
        'name'      => 'required|max:255|unique:clusters,name,' . $id . ',id',
        'countries' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I would up this again if I could :)

Comment: I'm using `Route::resource`, I got the `id` by using `$this->route('customer')->id`

Comment: with resource you can also use `Request::route('{model}')`

Answer (score 0):

1. you run in terminal 'php artisan route:list'
2. See list item PUT/PATCH method to see param in route/url like: user/{user}
3. $id = $this->$user
   (with $user is {user} in your route)
4. write rules
   'name' => 'unique:users,name,' .$id,